# Spring JPA repository save not supporting Single Table inheritance

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to insert data of user actions using Spring JPA Single table type inheritance. Below are my classes:

RmlAction.java - The super class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "entityType")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "rml_actions")
public abstract class RmlAction extends RmlBase {
//attributes
}
```

RmlProjectAction.java

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "PROJECT")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RmlProjectAction extends RmlAction {
//constructor
}
```

RmlEfsAction.java

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "EFS")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RmlEfsAction extends RmlAction {
//constructor
}
```

When I try to insert data using ActionRepository, it gives the below error

```
Hibernate: insert into rml_user (active, creation_date, last_modified_date, object_version, activated, directory_role, efs_id, efs_stack_id, email, login_id, organization, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into rml_efs_action (active, creation_date, last_modified_date, object_version, action_params, action_status, action_type, entity_id, job_id, message, published, user, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-02-03 15:53:43,767 WARN  [http-nio-5000-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2020-02-03 15:53:43,768 ERROR [http-nio-5000-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: Table 'rmldb.rml_efs_action' doesn't exist
```

Notice here that it is trying to insert into `rml_efs_action` table and I don't understand the reason. I tried multiple things but nothing works.

Comment: What is `RmlBase`? Add the code where you construct and save the entity.